# Как преобразовать XML данные в JSON и добавить автоматически вычисляемое поле?

Tags: python, json, xml, pandas

Мне нужно распарсить XML данные и конвертировать их в JSON для хранения в MongoDB. К данным нужно добавить дополнительный заголовки. Некоторые заголовки могут вычисляться: реализовываться как счетчик с автоинкрементом или вычисляться при помощи внешней функции.

Данные примерно такие:

```
<vpuStatusReply>
<vpu>
<vpuID value="795174117"/>
<vpuNumber value="062202"/>
<vpuStateID value="314"/>
<vpuState value="Согласован"/>
<vpuNeedForECP value="0"/>
<vpuLastOper value="10.06.2018 07:19:05"/>
<docPrice value="0"/>
</vpu>
<vpu>
<vpuID value="795174757"/>
<vpuNumber value="062203"/>
<vpuStateID value="314"/>
<vpuState value="Согласован"/>
<vpuNeedForECP value="0"/>
<vpuLastOper value="10.06.2018 07:23:32"/>
<docPrice value="0"/>
</vpu>
<vpu>
```

Преобразование выполняет этот код:

```
import json
import codecs
import untangle
import io
import xmltodict
import pandas

class Marshaler:
    def marshal_xml(self, xml_data):
        parsed = xmltodict.parse(xml_data)
        add_info = {
            'creatorId':'ETRANTEST',
            'sysId':0,
            'type':'document',
            'documentType':'ETRANvpuState'}
        df = (pandas.io.json.json_normalize(parsed['vpuStatusReply']['vpu'])
                .rename(columns=lambda c: c.replace('.@value', ''))
                .assign(**add_info))
        print(df)

with codecs.open('vpu.txt', 'r', 'utf-8') as f:
    xml = f.read()
    marshaler = Marshaler()
    result = marshaler.marshal_xml(xml)
```

Здесь поле `sysId` должно вычисляться и быть равным порядковому номеру записи (или следующее значение может возвращаться из внешней функции).

Как реализовать автоматические изменение поля `sysId`?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [54]: %paste
add_info = {
            'creatorId':'ETRANTEST',
            'sysId':np.arange(1, len(parsed['vpuStatusReply']['vpu'])+1),
            'type':'document',
            'documentType':'ETRANvpuState'}

df = (pd.io.json.json_normalize(parsed['vpuStatusReply']['vpu'])
        .rename(columns=lambda c: c.replace('.@value', ''))
        .assign(**add_info))

## -- End pasted text --

In [55]: df
Out[55]:
       vpuID vpuNumber vpuStateID    vpuState vpuNeedForECP          vpuLastOper docPrice  creatorId  sysId      type   documentType
0  795174117    062202        314  Согласован             0  10.06.2018 07:19:05        0  ETRANTEST      1  document  ETRANvpuState
1  795174757    062203        314  Согласован             0  10.06.2018 07:23:32        0  ETRANTEST      2  document  ETRANvpuState
```